# Finding integer points inside of a parallelogram

Tags: algorithms, linear-programming, plane-geometry, integer-programming

Suppose $P = \{p_1,\ldots,p_4\} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ defines a quadrilateral (here, specifically, a parallelogram). In the particular case I'm dealing with, I know that there exists at least one point with integer coordinates in the interior of $P$, though there are possibly many such points. I would like to find one of these points; ideally, a solution to finding such a point would not depend on knowing that one exists.

To reformulate (my lines will not generally be vertical), I want to find an integer solution $(x,y)$ to the equations 
\begin{eqnarray*}
y &<& ax + b_1, \\
y &>& ax + b_2, \\
y &<& cx + b_3, \\
y &>& cx + b_4.
\end{eqnarray*}

Is there a good way to tackle such a problem? Note that this can be an arbitrarily bad situation, such as having the parallelogram containing a small neighborhood of the line segment from $(0,0)$ to $(2^{107}-1,2^{127}-1)$, and such that many points are closer to the boundary lines than either of the two interior integral points.

[image: picture of integer lattice in the plane, and of thin diagonal rectangle with a single distinguished lattice point within]

Comment: This is a typical setting for *lattice basis reduction*
(which in 2D is closely related to the
Euclidean algorithm applied to $1$ and the slope of the parallelogram's 
longer edge, and to that slope's continued-fraction development).
Apply a linear transformation $T$ taking the parallelogram
to a unit square $S$, and ${\bf Z}^2$ to some lattice $L$.  Find a reduced
basis for $L$.  It is then easy (assuming no precision issues
with a point of $L$ coming very close to the boundary of $S$) to decide
whether $S \cap L$ contains some point $p$, and if yes to find such $p$.
Then recover $T^{-1}p$.

Comment: @Noam Elkies: Thank you; I wasn't sure what terms to look for, but that seems like enough to solve my problem.

Comment: @Noam and Eric: If Noam Elkies' comment answers the question, may I suggest that Noam repost it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to apply the algorithm from the paper

B. N. Delone, “An algorithm for the “divided cells” of a lattice”, Izv. Akad. Nauk SSSR Ser. Mat., 11:6 (1947), 505–538